# Is it possible to alter a holomorphic function such that it has a specific pole? (Complex Variables - Flanigan)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Just a quick True-False question from Complex Variables - Francis J. Flanigan

Could someone confirm my reasoning?

> *True or false?*
>
> If $f(z)$ holomorphic at the origin, then there exists an integer $n$ such that $g(z) = \dfrac{f(z)}{z^m}$ has a pole at the origin, provided $m>n$.

I would argue *false* since $f(z) = 0$ does not meet the conditions, while the book states *'true'*.

I think if the problem would state *"... nonconstant function $f(z)$ ..."* then $f(z)$ could be written as $f(z) = (z-z_0)^n g(z)$ where $g(z_0)\not = 0$ and this would meet the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. For every $m\in \Bbb{N}$, the function $z\mapsto \frac{0}{z^m}$ has a removable singularity at the origin.